# Story about a man whose mind is transported to the future into another person's body

Tags: story-identification

I can't seem to find a story I read sometime in the past – space opera / time travel.

The plot goes something like this: a man's mind is transported to the future where he finds himself in another's body, pretends to be him, then fights in a war, and is ultimately transported back to his own time.

The book has an apparent sequel, where the protagonist is transported again to the future in the same manner. I also seem to remember the second story retconning the ending of the first slightly.

Answer (score 15):

It's "[The Star Kings](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1514772.The_Star_Kings)" (1949) and "[Return to the Stars](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3973210-return-to-the-stars)" (1968) by Edmond Hamilton. Consciousness of John Gordon, ex bomber pilot, transported to the future into the body of prince Zarth Arn. In second book he was transported again, but in his own body.