# Seeking fantasy novel abt WW2 English officer who inhabits another's body on another world

Tags: story-identification

Seeking fantasy novel about a WW2 English officer who inhabits another's body on another world.  The Englishman's mind must struggle to survive in the fantasy world.  Title and author unknown.  Likely written in 3rd quarter of 20th century.  Started it once, decades ago, and am curious to see if I'd like the novel.  (Might be a terrible book?  But am still curious.)

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Star Kings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123066), except with a British protagonist instead of an American protagonist